# What does this Perl regex do?

Tags: regex, perl

What does the following snippet do?

```
if ($str =~ /^:(\w+)/) {  
       $hash{$1} = 1;  
}
```

It uses the first successful capture as key in the hash. And the `$str` has to contain one or more words but I am not sure what the `^:` means

Answer (score 6):

```
^       start at beginning of string
:       match a literal colon
(       capture the following string
\w+     matching one or more alphanumeric characters
)       end capture
```

The capture is stored in `$1`, which then becomes a key in the hash `%hash` below.

So if you have the string `:foo`, you will match `foo`, and get `$hash{foo} = 1`. The purpose of this code is no doubt to extract certain strings and dedupe them using a hash.

Answer (score 0):

`^:` mean ":" symbol at the start of the line. Also it will capture only **single** "word" after `:`

Answer (score 0):

It means `^` At the begin of the Line a `:`

e.g:

`$string = q~:Thats~;`

`$hash{Thats} = 1;`

`$string2 = q~Thats~;`

The `if` Statement is successfull at `$string`, but it fails at `$string2` because it doesn't start with an `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

```
'And the $str has to contain one or more words ...'
```

I'm not sure if this is simply a typo or if your intention is different from your small example. Now (according to your post), your regex would match a string like: `:Hello`. In Perl, this could be written also like

```
my %hash = ();
my $str = ':Hello';

$hash{ $1 }++ if $str =~ /^:(\w+)/;
```

Now, if you'd change `^:` in your regex to `[:^]`, which means: your word in your string should be preceded by '*start of string*' `^` OR a colon `:`, your regex could now match lines like: `'Hello:World:Perl:Script';` (maybe this was the real intention).

Such a string could then be dissected in a while loop:

```
$hash{ $1 }++ while $str =~ /[:^](\w+)/g;
```

If you print the captured keys: `print "@{[keys %hash]}";`
the result would be: `Perl Script Hello World` (the order of the keys is undefined).

These kinds strings are widespread in the unix world, e.g. the environment variables `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and also the file `/etc/passwd` looks like that.

BTW, this is only an idea - IF your typo wasn't really one ;-)